# How to know if a process is running in Windows in C++, WinAPI?

Tags: winapi

How do I know in a windows program if a process is running if I only know the exe file name ?
The process in question is TeamSpeak3 ts3client_win64.exe for 64 bit and ts3client_win32.exe for 32 bit.

I am using C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create a snapshot of the current process table, then use the [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to iterate the snapshot. You can get the name for each executable file by looking at the `szExeName` field of the [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

See [the MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a sample of how to use these functions.

The advantage of this approach is that, unlike any [`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629)-based solution, it doesn't suffer from race conditions: with `EnumProcesses` it can happen that a process gets destroyed after you finished enumerating the processes but before you got around to opening the process (or reading our the process executable name).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629), [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320), and [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198) (or alternatively, [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919) for Vista or later).  MSDN even has [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623).

Answer (score 1):

Windows NT has several APIs for enumerating processes.

1. [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629.aspx)
2. [ToolHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx)
3. [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx) (discouraged)
4. WMI's [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372.aspx) (works remotely)