# Substitute of EnumProcessModulesEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to iterate over processes currently running on a 64bit machine, EnumProcessModules works great with 32bit programs but isn't any good with 64bit ones, I tried Implementing EnumProcessModulesEx with Devc++ that I am using(don't have visualstudio) but couldn't manage to make the header files work, see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970345/enumprocessmodulesex-missing-in-psapi-h) , so was thinking if there is an another way out ?

In my program I need to know if a process executed by a particular exe is running or not, the process can be 32bit or 64bit, so need to check both.

Comment: If you just need to know whether some process is running or not, what do you need `EnumProcessModules` for?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I iterate over all the processes currently running, getting each one's module base name with GetModuleBaseName() then check the return string with the process I am looking for, something like if(basename.compare("myexe.exe") == 0) ....

Comment: So you want to know whether there's any process which was launched by some given executable name?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Yup exactly, damn I should have mentioned that. edited.

Comment: This is an example of the XY problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). You don't actually need a replacement for `EnumProcessModulesEx`, since you don't even need the function itself.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I did actually asked the x question and was adviced that y was the answer :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657455/how-to-know-if-a-process-is-running-in-windows-in-c-winapi

Comment: Indeed! I wasn't aware of your other question, sorry. :-) I answered there as well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumProcessModules` indeed requires that the calling process uses the same architecture (32bit vs. 64bit) as the target process. However, for your use case, you don't need that function.

It's more efficient (and doesn't suffer from race conditions...) to create a snapshot of the current process table and then iterate that snapshot, looking for the process name:

1. Call [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a snapshot of the process table
2. Use [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to iterate the snapshot.
3. For each element in the snapshot, check the `szExeFile` field (of the [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure) to get the executable name.

You probably want to do a case-insensitive comparison of the names, since file names on Windows are case insensitive.